Not Sure why Quadratic probing wont work to resolve collisions when hashing
I have a program that consists of two files, I have both a quadratic and linear probing function to resolve collisions while hashing and my Linear works fine but im not sure why the quadratic doesnt. I have the results that should be printed

Linear:
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 33: 6240629
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 37: 4817906
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 39: 6686453
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 41: 7423747Quadratic:
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 33: 1145326
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 37: 1182048
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 39: 1127766
Hash table size: 8087
Number of collisions with a = 41: 1152208
Instead, I get the following result for my output.

Hash table size : 8087
Number of collisions with a = 33: 1134428

Hash table size : 8087
Number of collisions with a = 37: 1166882

Hash table size : 8087
Number of collisions with a = 39: 1184105

Hash table size : 8087
Number of collisions with a = 41: 1159074

What Im talking about is the number of collisions. I need the values to match and they should because they are inputing the same code and both should be using quadratic probing. Below are my two files I would GREATLY appreciate any help. been stuck on this all day.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include "HashType - Copy.h"

using namespace std;

void buildHashTable(ifstream &inFile,
                    HashType<string> &hashTable,
                    int type,
                    int Prime)
{
    string word;
    int length;
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while (inFile >> word)
        {
            length = word.size();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < length;)
            {
                unsigned char ch = word[i]; // Cast to unsigned char to handle characters safely
                if (ch < ' ' || ispunct(ch))
                { // Check for control characters and punctuation
                    word.erase(i, 1);
                    length = word.length(); // Update length after modifying the string
                }
                else
                {
                    ++i; // Only increment if no deletion was made
                }
            }
            if (type == 1)
            {
                hashTable.InsertItemLinear(word, Prime);
            }
            
            if (type == 0)
            {
                hashTable.InsertItemQuadratic(word, Prime);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    cout << "\n" << "Hash table size : " << hashTable.GetSize() << endl;
    cout << "Number of collisions with a = " << Prime << ": "
            << hashTable.GetCollisions() << endl;
    hashTable.MakeEmpty();
    hashTable.resetCollisions();
    
}

int main()
{
    for (int b : { 33, 37, 39, 41 })
    {
        ifstream inFile("hashText1.txt");
        if (!inFile)
        {
            cerr << "Error opening file." << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        
        int primeSize;
        
        string line;
        
        if (getline(inFile, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            ss >> primeSize;
        }
        
        HashType<string> hashTable(primeSize);
        
        buildHashTable(inFile, hashTable, 0, b);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}

#ifndef HASHTYPE_H
#define HASHTYPE_H
// File ItemType.h must be provided by the user of this class. 
//  ItemType.h must contain the following definitions: 
//  MAX_ITEMS:     the maximum number of items on the list 
//  ItemType:      generic data type

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

const int MAX_ITEMS = 5;
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class HashType
{
public:
    HashType();
// Constructor
    HashType(int s);
//Dynamic size constructor
    void SetHashType(bool flag);
    void MakeEmpty();
// Function: Returns the list to the empty state.
// Post:  List is empty.
    bool IsFull() const;
// Function:  Determines whether list is full.
// Pre:  List has been initialized.
// Post: Function value = (list is full)
    int GetNumItems() const;
// Function: Determines the number of elements in list.
// Pre:  List has been initialized.
// Post: Function value = number of elements in list
    void RetrieveItem(ItemType item, bool &found);
// Function: Retrieves list element whose key matches item's key (if
//           present).
// Pre:  List has been initialized.
//       Key member of item is initialized.
// Post: If there is an element someItem whose value matches
//       item's value, then found = true and item contains the contents of
//       the item if it is found.
//      otherwise found = false and item is returned unchanged.
//       List is unchanged.
    void Insert(ItemType item);
// Function: Adds item to list and uses a linear probing technique to
// resolve collisions.  If the flag is true, a random hash method will be used.
//If the flag is false, the division method will be used.
// Pre:  List has been initialized.
//       List is not full.
//       item is not in list.
// Post: item is in list.
    void DeleteItem(ItemType item);
// Function: Deletes the element whose key matches item's key.
// Pre:  List has been initialized.
//       Key member of item is initialized.
//       One and only one element in list has a key matching item's key.
// Post: No element in list has a key matching item's key.
    int Hash(ItemType item, int a) const;
//This is the hash function for this class. If the flag is true, a random hash method will be used.
//If the flag is false, the division method will be used.
    
    unsigned long int GetCollisions() const;
//return the number of collisions that occured during the build of the hash table
    template<class Item>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const HashType<Item> &items);

    void InsertItemLinear(ItemType Item, int Prime);

    void InsertItemQuadratic(ItemType Item, int Prime);

    int GetSize();

    void resetCollisions();

private:
    bool hashType; //false is division method, true is a random folding method. default is false.
    unsigned long int numCollisions;
    int numItems;
    int size;
    ItemType *info;
    ItemType emptyItem = "";
};

template<class ItemType>
void HashType<ItemType>::resetCollisions()
{
    numCollisions = 0;
}

template<class ItemType>
int HashType<ItemType>::GetSize()
{
    return size;
}

template<class ItemType>
void HashType<ItemType>::SetHashType(bool flag)
{
    hashType = flag;
}

template<class ItemType>
HashType<ItemType>::HashType()
{
    hashType = false;
    numCollisions = 0;
    numItems = 0;
    size = MAX_ITEMS;
    info = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        info[i] = emptyItem;
}

template<class ItemType>
HashType<ItemType>::HashType(int s)
{
    hashType = false;
    numItems = 0;
    numCollisions = 0;
    size = s;
    info = new ItemType[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        info[i] = emptyItem;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
bool HashType<ItemType>::IsFull() const
{
    return (numItems == size);
}

template<class ItemType>
int HashType<ItemType>::GetNumItems() const
{
    return numItems;
}

template<class ItemType>
void HashType<ItemType>::MakeEmpty()
// Post: list is empty.
{
    numItems = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        info[i] = emptyItem;
}

//Updated IT via Dale 1/31/2019
template<class ItemType>
void HashType<ItemType>::DeleteItem(ItemType item)
{
    int location = 0;
    int startLoc;
    
    startLoc = Hash(item);
    location = startLoc;
    do
    {
        if (info[location] == item || info[location] == emptyItem)
        {
            info[location] = -1;
            numItems--;
            return;
        }
        else
            location = (location + 1) % size;
    } while (location != startLoc);
    
    if (location == startLoc)
    {
        cout << "Item to delete not found." << endl;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
int HashType<ItemType>::Hash(ItemType item, int a) const
// Post: Returns an integer between 0 and MAX_ITEMS -1.
{
//Complete code here
    int hash = 0;
    int n = item.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        hash = a * hash + item.at(i);
    return abs(hash % size);
    
    return 0;
}

template<class ItemType>
unsigned long int HashType<ItemType>::GetCollisions() const
{
    return numCollisions;
}

template<class ItemType>
void HashType<ItemType>::Insert(ItemType item)
// Post: item is stored in the array at position item.Hash()
//       or the next free spot.
{
    if (numItems / size > 0.70)
    {
//rehash//resize
    }
    int location;
    location = Hash(item);
    
    info[location] = item;
    numItems++;
}

template<class ItemType>
void HashType<ItemType>::RetrieveItem(ItemType item, bool &found)
{
    int location;
    int startLoc;
    bool moreToSearch = true;
    
    startLoc = Hash(item);
    location = startLoc;
    do
    {
        if (info[location] == item || info[location] == emptyItem)
            moreToSearch = false;
        else
            location = (location + 1) % size;
    } while (location != startLoc && moreToSearch);
    found = (info[location] == item);
    if (found)
        item = info[location];
}

template<class Item>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const HashType<Item> &items)
{
    out << "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < items.numItems; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            out << items.info[i];
        else
            out << ", " << items.info[i];
    }
    out << " ]" << endl;
    return out;
}


since I use the same hash function for linear and that works I dont think thats the problem. I had a similar issue with linear probing where the values were slightly off and solved it by changing my method for sorting through the file to input words. Im assuming that something similar will be the solution THANKS
edit:
input  https://pastebin.pl/view/ac731633

Recommendation: hardcode some data into main that demonstrates the problem. If you force people to go rogue they'll find and report on all sorts of stuff. Most of which you aren't interested in yet.

@user4581301 not sure what you mean by this could you clarify?

If I don't immediately see the problem in a question, one of the first things I do is crank up the diagnostics, build it, and run it myself. This is what I get: https://godbolt.org/z/W61Y6Wj9n No warning messages, a great start, but no useful output either. Makes it real hard to debug, not having input. If I invent my own input, I probably get different results than you do, and odds are I go chasing down a different bug than the one you're hunting. If you provide the input, that problem is reduced. If you build the input into the code so I don't have to load a file, even better.

@user4581301 sorry abouyt that here is the input, I also put it at the bottom of my post https://pastebin.pl/view/ac731633

What I'm trying to get you to do is remove the file entirely for this example, and build the file into a stringstream or similar directly in the program. You can't count on links to be accessible to all future readers of this question, and if a link is needed for those future readers to reproduce your problem so they can understand it, the question isn't useful to them.

A tactical note: Smaller, tightly focused questions are better than broad and long questions. With input, the smaller the input you need to reproduce the problem, generally the better you understand the problem. If you can show off  the problem with a few words, just use a few words. Using the US Constitution is not only overkill, it sometimes requires Captain Kirk to help interpret it.

Side note: GPT Zero is pretty sure the US Constitution is not AI generated.

tactical side recommendation note: Thanks for the help but how dare you use links. future generation wont be able to experience your HILAROUS jokes !
